# ASP.NET GridView SelectedIndexChanged not fired on async postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, gridview

I have seen a lot of forum topics on this issue; but none seem to fix it in my case. I have a GridView inside an Update Panel, which fires asynchronous postback on row click - this part is working. During the asynchronous postback though, the SelectedIndexChanged event handler is never called even though the postback passes through the Page_Load, RowDataBound, etc - pretty much all event handlers except the SelectedIndexChanged.

**Kindly refer to my makrup below:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnSorting="OnSorting" AutoGenerateColumns="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="outsideControl1" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="outsideControl2" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**And the code behind:**

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Panel, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
  }
}

protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ** Do stuff here **
}
```

I can see that the attribute "onclick" is added as the GridView does fire asynchronous postbacks whenever any of the rows is clicked. The problem is that the event handler OnSelectedIndexChanged is never called. I'm running out of ideas as to why a partial postback is made; but the event that caused it is not recognized.

**Here are some solutions I've tried, but obviously did not work:**

1.) Added the GridView as an Async Postback Trigger:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Since I have ChildrenAsTriggers="True", I knew this was unnecessary but I had to try anyway.

2.) Added the GridView as a full Postback Trigger:

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Still did not work, and I don't want this behavior anyway.

3.) Changed the attribute statement in row data bound as follows:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "__doPostBack('" + this.UniqueID + "$" + GridView.ID + "', 'Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex + "')";
```

This made a full postback instead of partial, and SelectedIndexChanged is still not called anyway.

4.) Tried to change the event from SelectedIndexChanged, to SelectedIndexChanging, or even RowCommand (as long as I can capture the calling Row)... but neither of them is called.

Please take note that this works perfectly for full postback if the GridView is not in the Update Panel. Unfortuantely, I need the postback to be asynchronous.

If anyone has ideas on what is happening, it will be greatly appreciated if you can share them. Thanks!

**Note:** Having a column with 'Select' buttons is not an acceptable solution (obviously I know this before asking this question). The rows have to be clickable themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Add to the GridView a TemplateField column with a `Select` button in it
2. In `RowDataBound`, hide the button cell and set the `CommandArgument` of the button to the row index
3. In the `onclick` event of the row, simulate a click on the invisible button

The markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnSorting="OnSorting" AutoGenerateColumns="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code-behind:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Hide cell with the display style, not with the Visible property
    e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btnSelect = e.Row.FindControl("btnSelect") as Button;
        btnSelect.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", btnSelect.ClientID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your idea is very logical. However, when I tried it, it still doesn't work. This works on full postback, but something in asynchronous postback avoids calling the event handler of the GridView for some reason. As with my previous examples, the row triggers partial postback but doesn't call the event handlers. I even tried making the buttons visible and directly clicking them as a test, but it leads to the same result.

Comment: It works well with the UpdatePanel in my own tests. The SelectedIndexChanged event handler is called, as are the other ones.

Comment: It seems like it should work as you described. My current setup is quite complicated now so there's probably something that's preventing this from working as it should. At this time, I just went for a workaround as I'm behind my deadline. +1 for your answer but I hope someone else can confirm this for future reference.

Comment: You could make a simple project and test this solution. If it works (as it does in my test project), you could gradually modify that project until it matches your real one, and see along the way where the problem shows up.

Comment: You are right, I tested this in an empty project and it works. Unfortunately for me my existing project is too complicated now and it would be counterproductive to follow your recommendation. It's great to know though that your approach works. I'll keep this in mind moving forward, thank you for the help!